# KDE login screen keyboard layout

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, login-screen

I use KDE with two keyboard layouts in it (EN and RU). My system password always has only english letters and digits. I never use differen from English languages in my passwords.

I also have global keyboard switching policy on. It is important, due to the fact, that I can't use another switching policy.

So, my idea is to force KDE login screen switch to english layout to decrease wrong password input cases.

Is it possible?

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: Do you mean actual login screen or lock screen. Because I have same layout set (en+ru) and haven't had any problem with login screen ever. Only with lock screen.

Comment: Yep, I meant lock screen, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

SDDM uses the system-wide keyboard layout on the login screen, but inherits the session keyboard layout on the unlock screen. This is a bad design that [causes friction and failed login attempts](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-linux-login-keyboard-layout.html), as you describe. This isn’t configurable in SDDM. You can try switching to something else, however. GDM, for example.

Answer (score 0):

try setting LayoutLoopCount=-1 in ~/.config/.kxkbrc
Here is my setup for this file:

```
[$Version]
update_info=kxkb.upd:remove-empty-lists,kxkb.upd:add-back-resetoptions,kxkb_variants.upd:split-variants
[Layout]
DisplayNames=,
LayoutList=us,ru
Options=grp:shift_caps_toggle,compose:ralt
ResetOldOptions=true
Use=true
VariantList=,
LayoutLoopCount=-1
SwitchMode=Window
```

Works for me. With per-window switching policy though.

If I understand [keyboard_daemon](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/37ac20a7c8f7dbe004af569ae6ceb3e4afc29886/kcms/keyboard/keyboard_daemon.cpp#L233) code right it will make KDE populate xkb layout list verbatim every time without taking previous value into account.

Comment: I already have `LayoutLoopCount=-1` value and it doesn't work

Comment: You're right. SwitchMode=Window is also required

Comment: what to do, if I don't have `~/.config/.kxkbrc` file? And what version to put instead of $Version?

Comment: $Version is exactly the text in the file. If you don't have ~/.config/.kxkbrc, create one